# Spring Boot 2 Upgrade Issue - Error Page Always returns HTML

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

I have recently upgraded our project to Spring Boot 2. The App is just a Rest API. And now all our 400 and 500 responses are being returned as html instead of json.

I am defining a custom ErrorAttributes, just like the docs say to do.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    ...

    @Bean
    public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
        return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {

            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(WebRequest webRequest,
                                                      boolean includeStackTrace) {
                Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, true);
                return errorAttributes;
            }

        };
    }

    ...
```

I would like to debug this issue locally, but I cannot find in the code where Spring Boot makes this decision to add a JSON Response for errors. The docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling says:

> For machine clients, it produces a JSON response with details of the error, the HTTP status, and the exception message.

I'm thinking that I must have a Bean defined locally that is causing this not to be configured correctly in the Spring Boot Auto configuration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my problem is due to my Spring Security / Keycloak configuration

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.  I think there were some changes in Spring Security 4 to Spring Security 5 that was causing a NPE early in the filter chain for our app. Also, compounding the difficulty of debugging the issue is that with the Spring Boot upgrade, the /error route was forced to be authenticated.

I ended up fixing the NPE, allowing for everyone to see the /error mapping and then making sure ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration was being initialized correctly. All is working now.